# Asking Questions using arrays and loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a quiz using JS and I want the questions to display and then if answer correct move on to next question, if not display correct answer and move on to next question.
I can't get the questions to display one at a time!

Code:

```
let questions = [
    ["1. Who is the current President of the U.S? ", "Joe Biden"],
    ["2. True or false: 60 minutes == 1 hour? ", "True"],
    ["3. How many months in a year? ", "12"]
];
let correctAnswers = 0;
    
for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    var answer = console.log (questions[i][0]);
    if (answer == questions[i][1]) {
        console.log ("Correct " + questions[i][1]);
        correctAnswers++;
    }
    else {
        console.log ("Incorrect, the correct answer was " + questions[i][1]);
    }
```

Comment: `console.log` doesn't prompt the user for anything - are you trying to run this in a browser? in a `node` environment? Maybe you were looking for `prompt(...)`?

Comment: I got it.  all good

Answer (score 0):

Here's a ***VERY*** quick and ***dirty*** way to achieve this. However a much better and more fail safe way would be to use multiple choice with select inputs so you control the values being entered for the questions as using a text input to answer a question could be tough matching the string for the answer, not to mention validation and cleansing input, etc...

EDIT: To display only one question at a time, you can use a data attribute, something like `data-answered` and by default set them all to false except the first one. Then place a conditional that checks the dataset in the event.targets parentNode, if true display the element using CSS `.flex-item[data-answered="true"]{ display: block: }` and `.flex-item[data-answered="false"]{ display: none; }` for the elements whose `dataset-answered` that are set to `false`. Then in the conditional returns a correct answer `if(answer.value === questions[i][1]){` we set the `parent.nextElementsSibling` dataset to true, then that question will be displayed.

```js
const display = document.getElementById('display')

let questions = [
  ["1. Who is the current President of the U.S? ", "Joe Biden"],
  ["2. True or false: 60 minutes == 1 hour? ", "True"],
  ["3. How many months in a year? ", "12"]
];
let correctAnswers = 0;

questions.forEach((question, i) => {
  // create the elements
  let label = document.createElement('LABEL')
  let input = document.createElement('INPUT')
  let div = document.createElement('DIV')
  // add class for style
  div.classList.add('flex-item')
  // set attribute for label
  label.setAttribute('for', i)
  // set textContent to question
  label.textContent = question[0]
  // set type for input and ID to index
  input.type = 'text'
  input.id = i
  // set only the first question to true using the index
  i < 1 ? div.dataset.answered = true : div.dataset.answered = false
  // append div with label and input
  div.append(label, input)
  // add elements to the dom 
  display.append(div)
})
// create button
let btn = document.createElement('BUTTON')
btn.textContent = 'Submit Answer'
// add button to dom
display.append(btn)


// function will check answers and check if dataset is true 
function checkEntries(e){ // pass the event into the function
  // get the events parent
  let parent = e.target.parentNode
  // get the inputs
  let answers = parent.querySelectorAll('input')
  // loop over the questions defining value and index
  answers.forEach((answer, i) => {
    // check answers
    if(answer.value === questions[i][1]){ 
      // add classes showing success or remove failure in case second try or second question
      answer.classList.add('success')
      answer.classList.remove('fail')
      // if right answer set the dataset to true
      // we use the input to target its parent and then get the nextElementSibling
      answer.parentNode.nextElementSibling.dataset.answered = true
      if(i === questions.length - 1){// we have answered all questions
        answer.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div class="success">Congratulations!</div>')
        document.querySelector('button').remove()
      }
    }else{
      answer.classList.add('fail')
    }     
  })
}
// event handler on click
btn.addEventListener('click', checkEntries)
```

```css
.flex-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-item label {
  flex: 2;
}

.flex-item input {
  flex: 1;
}

.success {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  color: darkgreen;
}

.fail {
  background-color: pink;
  color: darkred;
}

.flex-item[data-answered="true"]{
  display: block;
}

.flex-item[data-answered="false"]{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
```